# Phpspreadsheet зависает формирование ods на объединении колонок

Tags: php, xls, phpspreadsheet

Используется phpSpreadsheet 1.16 для формирования xls и ods файла. Xls файл формируется корректно а ods зависает на объединении колонок.
`$sheet->mergeCells("B".($counter).":D".($counter)); $sheet->mergeCells("E".($counter).":F".($counter)); $sheet->mergeCells("G".($counter).":H".($counter));`

В чём может быть проблема?